# About $\textrm{Hom}_Z(X,Z) = X$, contravariant Hom factor

Tags: abstract-algebra, functors

I have difficulty of computing some basic contravariant Hom functor.

basically, in the class, teacher write 
\begin{align}
\textrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z},X) = X
\end{align}
But i am not sure how this comes up.

Furthermore with above idea, he said one can compute

\begin{align}
&\textrm{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n) \\
&\textrm{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}) \\
& \textrm{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_n)
\end{align}
But i am not sure how to copmute or handle above expressions.

Any idea or hint or reference will be helpful.

Comment: maybe you should write $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of just Z and similarly for Z_m

Comment: It isn't true, $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z)=0$.  A map of abelian groups is determined by where it sends a generator, and an element of order $k$ must be sent to an element of order $k$ (where I mean $kx=0$, not necessarily that $k$ is the minimum number such that $kx=0$).  However, the only finite order element of $\mathbb Z$ is $0$ itself.  Perhaps your teacher meant $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z,X)=X$.  Here, a map out of $\mathbb Z$ is determined by the image of $1$, which can be any element of $X$.

Comment: @Aaron, i correct the statement. At that case how one compute $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_m, \mathbb{Z}_n)$?, from the $hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z})=0$, naviley i can guess it is related to $gcd(m,n)$, but how i can construct a map like $kx=0$?

Comment: If you let $1$ be a generator of $\mathbb Z_m$, then that generator can be sent to any element $x\in\mathbb Z_n$ such that $mx=0$.  You should work out what this subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n$ is. I do believe that your guess (that it is related to $\gcd(m,n)$) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'm writing this at a level aimed at an intro algebra class; do let me know if this is comes across as too condescending or conversely, confusing.]

I'll clarify the first one and leave the rest to you. (Let me know in the comments if you figure it out!)

I'm assuming here (you should have specified!) that we're working in the category of groups (this means that the object $X$ is a group and all the maps in the hom-set are group homomorphisms). So $\textrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z},X)$ consists of all the group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $X$.

However, $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by a single element, say $1$. That is, given any other element $n$ in $Z$, I can just add $1$ and perhaps its inverse $-1$ some number of times to get $n$.

Note what this means for homomorphisms out of $\mathbb{Z}$. If I tell you where a homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to X$ sends $1$, you can figure out what $\phi$ does to all the other elements (try writing this out if this isn't clear). Moreover, for every single element $x \in X$, I can define a map $\mathbb{Z} \to X$ by setting $\phi(1) = x$.

That is, we have a bijection betwen $\textrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z},X)$ and $X$.